# Referencing a particular cell value when there are two string matches in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a predictive algorithm in VBA that would search for strings in a particular row from a data source, and return a value based on the row number. This is the first step in the workflow, and in its simplest form, there are 2 tables as shown below:

Source Table:

[image: This is the source table, on which the strings will be searched.]

Output Table:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Pick up the strings in Row 1 of Output Table (Blue,Black) and search for them in Rows 1,2,3,4 of Source Table.
2. If both strings match in a single row, the 'Input' cell from that particular row is copied to Row 1 in Output Table in the 'Output' column.

Example (2nd iteration):
From Output Table Row 2, strings Ivory,Green,Grey are picked up and queried in all rows of Source Table. If any 2 out of 3 strings match in a single row on Source Table, the Input cell of that row is copied.

In this case, Ivory and Green match in Row 1, and also in Row 4. Either input cell would work, but for the sake of having a rule, lets take the last match (Row 4). So '1,8' would be copied to Row 2 on Output Table.

This the flow I am currently using, but I'm getting an incorrect output:

```
For i = 2 To 5
For j = 1 To 4
For k = 2 To 5
For l = 1 To 5

If Cells(i, j).Value = Worksheets("SourceTable").Cells(k, l).Value And Cells(i,j).Value <> "" Then
For a = 1 To 5
For b = 1 To 4

If Cells(i, b).Value = Worksheets("SourceTable").Cells(k, a).Value And Cells(i, b).Value <> "" Then
Cells(i, 15).Value = Worksheets("SourceTable").Cells(k, 5).Value
GoTo iLoop
End If

Next b
Next a
End If

Next l
Next k
Next j
iLoop:
Next i
```

Both tables would have around half a million rows, and I am trying to figure out how to reduce the number of loops and make it work at the same time. Any suggestions would be appreciated, this would help me save a lot of man-hours and automate a major chunk of the process. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `mysql` database?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it's on Excel as of now

Comment: How many strings have to match? In the first example it is 2/2. In the second example it is 2/3. Is it always at least 2? What about if there is only one string in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub macro()
lastRowOut = Sheets("OutputTable").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowSou = Sheets("SourceTable").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRowOut
    For j = 2 To lastRowSou
        If checkRow(j, i) >= 2 Then
            Sheets("OutputTable").Cells(i, 5) = Sheets("SourceTable").Cells(j, 6)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
Function checkRow(sRow, i)
lastCol = Split(Sheets("OutputTable").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")(1)
counter = 0
For Each cell In Sheets("OutputTable").Range("A" & i & ":" & lastCol & i)
    If Not Sheets("SourceTable").Range("A" & sRow & ":" & "E" & sRow).Find(cell.Value) Is Nothing Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cell
checkRow = counter
End Function
```

Quite a few things are unclear so here were the assumptions I made:

- Two or more of the cells in a row in the OutputTable have to be matched for the prediction to be made.
- The first rows of both the Output and Source sheet contain "Col1, Col2" etc.
- You seem to not mind whether we use the first or last matching row (from the source sheet) so I went with the first.
  That's 3 loops instead of 6..

Comment: This works and has an optimum number of loops. One exception that I hadn't mentioned earlier is this: Example, in Output Table row 2, if we have Blue,Black,Blue, your algo would show an output of 1,2,3, instead it should be blank, since Blue is a repetition and would not be counted twice. Would this be possible in this code?

Comment: At the beginning of `checkRow` declare an array. Then, at the beginning of the `For Each` loop, use `IsError (Application.Match(cell.value, myArray, 0))` to check whether we have checked this item already. If we haven't (i.e. `IsError` returned `True`) then we add `cell.value` to the array.

Comment: Done, the duplicate issue is solved too, Also, I have added this line Sheets("OutputTable").Cells(i, 6) = checkRow(j, i) to output the number of matches, this helps to segregate the higher probability rows. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim row As Range

    With Worksheets("OutputTable")
        For Each row In .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Rows '<--| change "D" to "OutputTable" sheet last "col" column index (i.e. the one before "Output" column)
            SearchSource row
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub SearchSource(rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, row As Range
    Dim nFounds As Long

    With Worksheets("SourceTable")
        For Each row In .Range("E2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Rows '<--| change "E" to "SourceTable" sheet last "col" column index (i.e. the one before "Input" column)
            nFounds = 0
            For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Not row.Find(what:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then nFounds = nFounds + 1
                If nFounds = 2 Then Exit For
            Next
            If nFounds = 2 Then rng.Cells(, rng.Columns.count + 1).Value = row.Cells(, row.Columns.count + 1).Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I needed to put in an exception which I didn't mention earlier. Example: in Output Table row 2, if we have Blue,Black,Blue, your algo would show an output of 1,2,3, instead it should be blank, since Blue is a repetition and would not be counted twice. Another thing is the number of matches, does your code imply greater than or equal to 2 matches, or equal to 2 matches? (The former would be appropriate in this case).

Comment: well this site is for helping people with their code attempts you could first make your attempt at modifying my code as per your _new_ needs and, should you get stuck, come with a new post. furthermore since my answer solved your original question, you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'Try this:

'First declare some variables:

'the number of rows of the Output table

```
 Dim OrNum as integer
```

'the number of columns of the Output table

```
 Dim OcNum as integer
```

'the number of rows of the Source table

```
 Dim SrNum as integer
```

'the number of columns of the Source table

```
 Dim ScNum as integer
```

'some dummy variables for the loops

```
 Dim rO as integer, cO as integer 

 Dim rS as integer, cS as integer
```

And then declare a boolean variable (just for later on)

```
Dim bool as boolean
```

'Then assume the output table has it's first cell at the most 'top and the most left of the output table, which is taken to 'be the cell Z1 in the following Code

'Begin with this first cell of the Output table and get each 'value in a way, that you move first (inner loop) over the 'columns by fixing the row Index (rO) of the Output table and then (outer loop) get down to each and every row like this:

```
For rO = 0 to OrNum - 1
    For cO = 0 to OcNum - 1
       Range("Z1").Offset(rO, cO)
    Next 
Next
```

'Now you don't have only strings so you will need to check, 'if the value in the cell is a string or a number. There is VBA 'function, that can help. It's called IsNumeric. It will give 'True if the value is a numeric value. If we have a string, then it will give False. With the Function IsEmpty() you can also check if a cell is empty or not. If a cell is empty, then the function IsEmpty will return True.

```
For rO = 0 to OrNum - 1
     For cO = 0 to OcNum - 1
     bool = IsNumeric(Range("Z1").Offset(rO, cO).Value)
     bool = bool Or IsEmpty (Range("Z1").Offset(rO, cO).Value)
         If bool=False then 
 'we have a string!
 'do something 
          End if
      Next 
Next
```